# What can be the consequences of using google webmaster tools for my youtube video downloader website?

Tags: google-search-console, youtube

Will it be blocked/spam-listed if google detects that it provides youtube-video downloading ?

Comment: Um, yes. They would probably block you as you are violating their terms of service.

Comment: Can you expand on what you mean by 'youtube video downloader' website?

Comment: @mezzo The site provides download iink for video/audio/playlist when a user inputs a youtube link. Here - https://www.cpclips.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took a chance and registered on Google Webmaster Tools as well as Google Analytics, and it has been over a year and I haven't faced any problem. Hopefully, it will be the same in the future.